# Given two int arrays, return an array of length 2 containing as much will fit from the first and second array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to solve the exercise bellow. I don't get any compiler errors.

When I run it though, in the main method only the first `Make2` gets called and the program stops working with this error:

`The program '[4864] Make2Two.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).`

Could someone help me with that?

And is there any better way to solve the problem? I think I put too much unnecessary code.

Thanks a lot.

**Problem:**  Given 2 int arrays, a and b, return a new array length 2 containing, 
as much as will fit, the elements from a followed by the elements from b. The arrays may be any length, including 0, but there will be 2 or more elements available between the 2 arrays.

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Make2Two
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Make2(new int[] { 4 }, new int[] { 4, 2, 3 }); //output 44
            Make2(new int[] { 2, 3 }, new int[] { 2, 3, 6 }); //the others are not running
            Make2(new int[] { 2, 5 }, new int[] { 7, 6, 5 });
        }
        public static int[] Make2(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            int[] result = new int[2];
            if (a.Length >= 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    result[i] = a[i];
                    Console.Write(result[i]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (a.Length < 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    result[0] = a[0];
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++)
                        {
                            result[j] = b[j - 1];
                            for (int k = 0; k < result.Length; k++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(result[k]);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think you are overcomplicating it a little...

And your code is wrong:

```
result[0] = a[0];
```

How can you be sure that `a` has at least one element? You should check it!

Let's try in another way: three indexes: `i` (index of `result`), `ai` (index of `a`), `bi` (index of `b`). We always increment `i`. We increment `ai` or `bi` when we respectively take an element from `a` or from `b`.

```
public static int[] Make2(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] result = new int[2];

    for (int i = 0, ai = 0, bi = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ai < a.Length)
        {
            result[i] = a[ai];
            ai++;
        }
        else if (bi < b.Length)
        {
            result[i] = b[bi];
            bi++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.Write(result[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return result;
}
```

Another possible solution. Here we have two `for` cycles, one for `a` and one for `b`. The index `i` for `result` is shared.

```
public static int[] Make2(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] result = new int[2];

    int i = 0;

    for (int ai = 0; i < result.Length && ai < a.Length; i++, ai++)
    {
        result[i] = a[ai];
        Console.Write(result[i]);
    }

    for (int bi = 0; i < result.Length && bi < b.Length; i++, bi++)
    {
        result[i] = b[bi];
        Console.Write(result[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return result;
}
```

Addendum: if you want to check that your algorithm works, you should check corner cases like:

```
Make2(new int[] { }, new int[] { 1, 2 }); // output 12
Make2(new int[] { 4, 5 }, new int[] { }); // output 45
Make2(new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { 5 }); // output 15
```

Note that in general, functions that do calculations and functions that write should be separate, so you should remove all the `Console.Write` from `Make2` and put them in a separate method, that should be called by the `Main` method.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
int[] a = new int[5];
int[] b = new int[5];

var result = a.Concat (b).Take (2).ToArray();
```

PS: Would recommend reading about LINQ (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx)

Comment: Haha, A bit late to post, but yeah this is way I'd go with it.

Comment: @xanatos read the excercise. There are garanteed to be 2 elements : 'The arrays may be any length, including 0, but there will be 2 or more elements available between the 2 arrays'

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int[] arr=new int[2];


  if(a.length>=2){
    arr[0]=a[0];
    arr[1]=a[1];
    return arr;
  }
  if(a.length==1){
    arr[0]=a[0];
    arr[1]=b[0];
    return arr;

  }
  if(a.length==0){
    arr[0]=b[0];
    arr[1]=b[1];
    return arr;
  }
  return arr;




}
```

Comment: add more details

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int[] array = new int[2];
  
  int counter = 0;

 for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
   if(counter < 2)
     array[counter++] = a[i];
 }
 for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
 {
   if(counter < 2)
     array[counter++] = b[i];
 }
  return array;
}
```

Run separate for loops to check the elements in each array.

Comment: Take an additional counter variable and run up to the length of new array.

Answer (score -2):

```
public int[] plusTwo(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int res[]=new int[4];

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        res[i]=a[i];
        res[i+2]=b[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Given 2 int arrays, each length 2, return a new array length 4 containing all their elements.

plusTwo([1, 2], [3, 4]) → [1, 2, 3, 4]
plusTwo([4, 4], [2, 2]) → [4, 4, 2, 2]
plusTwo([9, 2], [3, 4]) → [9, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: please edit your answer and add there your description from comment.

Comment: Code without explanation is not recommended. Please provide how/why this resolves the problem.